# Spring boot error mapping on REST client

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot maps all error to /error , can we segregate the error , like if we are getting DB error then we show different message , if the path is incorrect we show a different error. I tried the below , but i want to give some message based on the Http Status and don't want to redirect on some page

```
    @Configuration
  class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {

    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "/400"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "/403"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/404"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, "/405"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/500"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED, "/501"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.BAD_GATEWAY, "/502"));
    container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, "/503"));
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot already supports custom error pages; you can add static HTML in `resources/public/error/` or template files in `resources/templates/error/`.

See ["Custom error pages" in Spring Boot reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-error-handling-custom-error-pages).